# How to select a card in a set of stock cards before entering data?

Tags: excel, vba

I downloaded a macro from Get Digital Help:

```vb
Sub AddText()
Dim Lrow As Single

Lrow = Worksheets ("Sheet 1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B & Lrow & ":C" & Lrow)=Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B3:C3").Value
```

This works for a single card. However I have numerous cards and need to select the appropriate card before using a macro like the above.

The information below may clarify the situation.
I am working on a set of stock control cards (68 individual cards) which have input columns "B" for the quantity sold and column "C" for the date sold.
The quantity and dates are to be picked from cells "P1" for the quantity and "Q1" for the date.
The stock card to be selected for the input comes from cell "R7". this cell gives the item number (i.e. the card number to have the entry made).
The existing macro below selects the correct stock card numbered in range "R7" and places the cursor on the first entry row in column "B".
I now need to enter the quantity sold and date in the next empty row down.
I cannot get the cursor to move beyond

```
Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("C2:C4012").Find(Range("R7").Value.Select
```

The following last part of the macro is what I thought would input the data into the appropriate cells but does not appear to do anything.

```vb
Lrow=Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1
Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B" & Lrow & ":C" & Lrow)=Worksheets ("Nail Cards").Range("P1:Q1).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Do  you understand what this code is doing?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Lrow, "B").Resize(1, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B3:C3").Value`  Other than that, if you need assistance you'd need to give us more information about exactly what the code needs to do.  We have no idea what you mean by "card" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
Lrow = Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("B" & Lrow & ":C" & Lrow) = Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("P1:Q1").Value
```

will insert the data from the range P1:Q1 on the sheet named "Nail Cards" to the next empty cells in columns B and C

Comment: Thanks for the information and it is correct however the problem lies with the earlier part of the macro

Comment: Thanks. The macro given will not work as it appears to prevented from doing so by the earlier part of the macro which selects the card range ie                            
 Worksheets("Nail Cards").Range("C2:c4012").Find(Range("R7").Value).Offset(8,-).Select  This seems to prevent the rest of the macro from running. I believe this is wher the problem lied.